Solve beam equation with elastic term using scipy solve_bvp
I want to solve the beam equation with distributed load and elatic term (which depends on how much the beam interact with the terrain) :
$$
EI\frac{d^4w}{dx^4}+k*(w(x)-t(x))=q(x)
$$
where $q(x)$ is a distributed load, k is the stiffness constant and $t(x)$ is the profile of the terrain.
In this formulation the elastic force are proportional to the term $w(x)-t(x)$ which tells us (or at least I think it should) how much the beam is "piercing" throught te terrain.
This is the python code:
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

EI = 10000  # Example value for EI
k = 10000000.0   # Example value for k

# Define the non-homogeneous term q(x)
def q(x):
    return -1 

def p(x):
    return np.sin(x)

def deltay(y, p):
    diff = y - p
    diff[np.where(diff>0)] = 0
    return diff

# Define the system of first-order differential equations
def system_of_eqs(x, y):
    y1, y2, y3, y4 = y
    dydx = np.vstack([y2, 
                  y3, 
                  y4, 
                  (- k * deltay(y1, p(x)) + q(x)) / EI])
    return dydx

# Define the boundary conditions
def bc(ya, yb):
    return np.array([ya[0]-1, yb[0]-1, ya[1], yb[1]])

# Initial guess for the solution
x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 10000)+ np.pi/2
y = np.zeros((4, x.size))

# Solve the boundary value problem
sol = solve_bvp(system_of_eqs, bc, x, y)

# Plot the solution
x_plot = x
y_plot = sol.sol(x_plot)

plt.plot(x_plot, y_plot[0], label='w(x)')
plt.plot(x_plot, p(x_plot), label="sin(x)")
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()

But I guess, I am missing something, since for example for the value of $k=10^7$, I always get the following results, no matter the $q(x)$

Or if I take $k=10^4$ and $q(x) = -100 $

Which I do not understand.
Do you have any suggestion?

I don't understand the meaning of the t(x) term in your equation. The reason your results look strange is that the large magnitude of this term is overwhelming the elastic displacements.

If you check sol.success, you get False, meaning that the algorithm did not converged to the desired accuracy.

I think the reason for the convergence failure is the outrageously fine starting mesh. A value like 10 or 100 will work.

Thanks for the comments!. Using the function t(x), I aim to model the terrain's reaction to the presence of a beam. In the code, the terrain profile is represented by a sin(x) function. If the value of w(x) at any point is less than the value of t(x), this indicates that a spring at that location is compressed by an amount t(x)−w. This compression results in an elastic response of k⋅(t(x)−w), where k is the spring constant.
